# Geometric Series of a Linear Application

Tags: real-analysis

Given a complete normed vector space of finite dimension E ( Banach space ), does the infinite geometric series of a matrix L which belongs to the linear and continuous applications of E to E converge ? To what limit ? I don't know if the way to treat this problem is similar to that of a geometric series. 
I think that in the case of treating the absolute convergence, it is clear that given the norm i would approach the way of considering the geometric series.

Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Does the geometric series on the real line converge for all real numbers? What is the equivalent condition for matrices?

Comment: No it doesn't. You actually repeated or reformulated my question. Considering some condition on the eigenvalues might by a way but i am not sure if the properties of a geometric series in the case of linear applications allow this.

Comment: Consider the operator norm on linear applications, it works in infinite dimensions as well

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\|A^n x\|\le\|A\|^n \cdot\|x\|$$